# Javascript reducing to the sum of an array of arrays of integers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays of integers that looks like this `[[5, 3], [2,1], [4, 3]]` and the output I am expecting is `[8, 3, 7]`, but I seem to be missing something in my reduce function, as I'm getting an array of `n undefined values` like `[undefined, undefined, undefined]` since n=3

How can I get the sum of each array in the arrays and load that into an array?

```js
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;

const dayArray = [[3,5],[4,6],[8,2]];

const twoWeekArray = dayArray.map((day, index) => {
  return day.reduce(reducer);
});

console.log(twoWeekArray);
```

Comment: You don't return from the map's arrow function

Comment: edited to return the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return:

```
dayArray = [[3,5],[4,6],[8,2]];
twoWeekArray = dayArray.map((day, index) => {
    return day.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    });
});
```

Comment: BTW You can also use arrow functions. In that case, you don’t need to return.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

```js
const subject = [[5, 3], [2,1], [4, 3]]

const result = 
  subject.map((elem) => 
    elem.reduce((acum, current) =>
      acum = acum + current,
      0
    )
   )
   

console.log(result)
```

Comment: what if we dont know the number of values in each array?

Comment: I changed it to fit your new requirements.